# Java GLFW segfault when using GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER

Tags: java, opengl, segmentation-fault, lwjgl, glfw

Whenever I use `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` to draw my objects, GLFW throws me a segfault on `glfwSwapBuffers();`

Here's the problematic code:

```
public Mesh( float[] verts, int[] indices ) {
    indicesCount = indices.length;

    vertexBuffer = glGenBuffers();
    elementBuffer = glGenBuffers();
    vertexArray = glGenVertexArrays();

    glBindVertexArray( vertexArray );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 6 * 4, 0 * 4 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 6 * 4, 3 * 4 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

    // Uncommenting this code causes segfault
    //glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer );
    //glBufferData( elementBuffer, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
}

public void draw() {
    glBindVertexArray( vertexArray );

    //glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer );
    //glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
    glBindVertexArray( 0 );
}
```

Segfault is caused by this code:

```
System.out.println( "Hello" );  // <- Would get printed 
glfwSwapBuffers( windowID );    // <- SIGSEGV
System.out.println( "Hello2" ); // <- Would not get printed
```

I am using latest LWJGL version 3.2.0, although I also tried 3.1.6, to no avail. I am completely lost, and if nothing works I guess I'll just have to stick to using C++, cause the same code works perfectly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) has to be the target (`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) to which the buffer object is bound and not the named buffer object. `glBufferData` affects the named buffer which is bound to the target.

Use the following code to solve your issue:

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer );
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```